# Receive mysql data with function()

Tags: php, mysql

I have written this function , but `return $director_name` not working , my editor show This error : undefined Variable

```
function get_director($id){

global $db ;

$query ='
    SELECT
        director_name
    FROM
        movie_directors
    WHERE
        director_id = '.$id;

$result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
$row =mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
extract($row);
return $director_name;
```

}

and this is my php code

```
<?php
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo('<tr class="data">');
                    extract($row);
                   $director = $get_director($movie_director);
                    echo('<td>'.$movie_title.'</td>');
                    echo('<td>'.$movie_year.'</td>');
                    echo('<td class="director_field"><a href="#">'.$director.'</a></td>');
                    echo('<td>'.$movie_actor.'</td>');
                    echo('<td>'.$movie_genre.'</td>');
                }
            ?>
```

PHP here show msg :`Fatal error: Function name must be a string`

please Help ME thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
$director = $get_director($movie_director);
```

as

```
 $director = get_director($movie_director);
```

Comment: thanks , What a stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Its not return its your query that might be not executing as you are passing parameter within function `$id` and within your query

```
$query ='SELECT director_name FROM movie_directors WHERE director_id = '.id;
                                                                        ^^^
```

it should be

```
$query ='SELECT director_name FROM movie_directors WHERE director_id = '.$id;
                                                                        ^^^
```

The error itself shows you need to change

```
$director = $get_director($movie_director);
```

into

```
$director = get_director($movie_director);
```

> And you are using deprecated **mysql** try using **PDO** or **mysqli**

Comment: Thanks man , But I did not solve my issue